# Does cloning React elements that are server components cancel the performance benefit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-server-components, react-hoc

I have been trying out React Server Components in NextJS 13. I have stumbled on a case when I need to use the pattern of [passing server components as props](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#recommended-pattern-passing-server-components-to-client-components-as-props) in a client component. The thing is, this is a HOC wrapper that attaches an `onClick` handler to each of its children.

Now, the way to do it in React is to call `cloneElement` with the new prop. I am no expert of React internals, especially when it comes to server components, so I wonder whether it would cause the server component to be rerendered on the client and thus cancel the performance benefits of using them?